# how to install SSL Pinning on flutter?

Tags: flutter, ssl, ssl-certificate, mitmproxy, pinning

anyone understand the error in this ??, I'm trying to install SSL pinning (previously asked), about this why?

the PEM certificate already exists ... but an error message like this appears

```
tlsexception (tlsexception: failure trusting builtin roots (os error: bad_pkcs12_data(pkcs8_x509.c:614), errno = 0))
```

Comment: The error message says it all: `Bad PKCS12 data`. hence it expects a .p12 file not a .pem file.

Comment: for this problem I have finished, because I have created the correct pem certificate, but for now I am confused because the user is not readable when using a different endpoint